# bash subshell command execution order with su

Tags: bash, shell

Normally I expect bash to execute commands in order when separated by a semicolon

eg, cmd1 executes before cmd2 in: `cmd1;cmd2`

But I've come across a scenario where this doesn't hold true.

```
echo 'my password' | sudo -S su -c "echo a 1>&2 ; $(echo b 1>&2)" root
```

I would expect the output to be

```
a
b
```

but it's actually

```
b
a
```

**Why?**

Is this something to do with the c flag for the su command? It only seems to occur when I put the 2nd command in a subshell.

Note that the IO redirection isn't the culprit - I added that in only to make an easy way to demonstrate my issue. If you put different commands there, like a `cd`, and a `stat`,  you'll see they're really executed out of order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ echo "hello $(echo world)"
hello world
```

`$( ... )` runs the command inside and substitutes the collected output, i.e. the command above ends up running `echo "hello world"`.

Similarly,

```
sudo -S su -c "echo a 1>&2 ; $(echo b)"
```

would end up running

```
sudo -S su -c "echo a 1>&2 ; b"
```

But with `$(echo b 1>&2)` the command writes `b` to stderr (and nothing to stdout), so while the shell is processing the string you see `b` appearing on the screen, and then the whole `$( ... )` construct is replaced by nothing (because it writes nothing to stdout).

What ends up running is

```
sudo -S su -c "echo a 1>&2 ; " root
```

---

If all you want to do is run a command in a subshell, that's `( ... )`, not `$( ... )`.

Comment: I'm not strong at scripting, so perhaps I'm wrong, but this explanation sounds way off. Consider this variation: `echo 'my password' | sudo -S su -c "cd /etc ; $(stat passwd)" root`.

Comment: @goat That starts by expanding the `$( ... )`, which causes an error because there's no `passwd` in the current directory. Then it runs `echo 'my password' | sudo -S su -c "cd /etc ; " root`.

Comment: @goat You can reduce it to this, btw: `echo "The output of the command was: $(stat passwd)"`

Comment: oh....you're saying that $(...) gets evaluated at the top level before anything gets passed to sudo/su?

Comment: @goat Yes, exactly! But even if it didn't, your code wouldn't make sense anyway: Try running `$(stat /etc/passwd)` at the command prompt. It'll just say something like `File:: command not found` because it's trying to run the output from `stat` as a new command.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. btw these are contrived examples. I changed `$(` to `\$(` and now it's working how I expect/want. Thanks!